# How to set Konsole key bindings in 16.10?

Tags: kde, konsole

I updated to Kubuntu 16.10 and realized that it's no longer possible to use Konsole. It has completely different key bindings and it's not easy to change those bindings at all.

For example TAB is not longer a completion, it's just paste of the `\t` symbol.

When I try to change it I see only: 
[image: how to edit keybindings]

What does that `\E[3~` mean?.. is it a bug?..

But the question is how to change, for example, TAB key to command completion instead of just putting `\t`?

The version of Konsole is 16.04.3

Comment: why wouldn't it do command completion? It sounds more like your shell has that feature disabled.

Comment: @MarkYisri command completion works in other terminals, it seems like it's only Konsole problem

Comment: @MarkYisri ok, completion works now, it was just not /bin/bash but something else. But still how can I change key bindings is not clear

Answer (score 0):

In konsole, you can go to settings -> edit current profile -> keyboard to modify your key bindings. You can also use your own defined keyboard with mappings specified in your own keymap file.